# "Лингвистические" анекдоты про Штирлица

Tags: фольклор

Тут мне попался один вопрос, где цитировался веселый рассказ про Штирлица. А мне подумалось другое: интересно, почему больше половины анекдотов про Штирлица заключаются игре слов? Посудите сами:
*"Штирлиц выстрелил в упор. Упор упал".

"Из форточки дуло. Штирлиц закрыл форточку. Дуло исчезло".

"Штирлиц склонился над картой СССР. Его неудержимо рвало на родину".*
И еще множество других.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что легендарный Штирлиц   с его точным и аналитическим умом неприязненно относился к полисемии - многозначности русских слов.

Поэтому подобные анекдоты - это пародия на логику его мышления, воспринимающую только прямое значение слова и отвергающую любой перенос, который обычно основан на мышлении образном.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае все относительно понятно: пафосный закадровый голос фильма Лиозновой так и просится, чтобы его спародировали. Да и сами каламбуры с подобной интонацией смотрятся лучше.

Из героев анекдотов более странным персонажем, по-моему, выглядит поручик Ржевский, так как его образ в анекдотах и в фильме (Гусарская баллада) почти не сочетаются.

Comment: Просто героем анекдотов стал другой Ржевский. Тоже поручик, только из более поздней эпохи. Хулиган, прославившийся тем, что выехал на Невский нагим.